# integration_test Depends on Old Version of test_api (0.4.3) - How Can I Upgrade?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dependencies, integration-testing

I'm trying to keep all my dependencies up to date, but `integration_test` and `flutter_test` seem to depend on `test_api` 0.4.3, and won't accept versions higher than this. I've had this problem for several months. I've watched several Flutter versions roll by. Each time, I think it will be fixed, and the problem remains. I currently have installed

`Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable`

The current version of `test` is 1.20.1 but if I try to use the latest package, I get this error when I do a `flutter pub get`

> Because test >=1.20.0 depends on test_api 0.4.9 and every version of integration_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.3, test >=1.20.0 is incompatible with
> integration_test from sdk.
> So, because assets_app depends on both integration_test from sdk and test ^1.20.1, version solving failed.

I checked out the [package](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9cdad24df0f94c371bb11e53284b10765f3517b0/packages/integration_test/pubspec.yaml#L37) on GitHub for `integration_test` and as you can see, it points to 0.4.9 of `test_api`. So, the only thing I can think of is that the current Flutter SDK points to an older version of  `integration_test`.

It looks as though `test` is generally outdated because if I try to upgrade `analyzer`, I get this:

> Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.3 and test >=1.20.0 depends on test_api 0.4.9, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.20.0.
> And because test >=1.17.10 <1.20.0 depends on analyzer >=1.0.0 <3.0.0 and test >=1.16.6 <1.17.10 depends on analyzer ^1.0.0, if flutter_test from sdk and test >=1.16.6 then analyzer >=1.0.0 <3.0.0.
> And because test >=1.16.1 <1.16.6 depends on analyzer >=0.39.5 <2.0.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.10 <1.16.1 depends on analyzer >=0.36.0 <0.42.0, if flutter_test from sdk and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.10 then analyzer >=0.36.0 <3.0.0.
> And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test <1.3.0 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0-∞, if flutter_test from sdk and test <1.3.0-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 or >=1.16.0-nullsafety.10 then analyzer >=0.36.0 <3.0.0.
> And because test >=1.3.0 <1.16.0-nullsafety depends on yaml ^2.0.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 depends on yaml ^2.0.0, if flutter_test from sdk and test any then analyzer >=0.36.0 <3.0.0 or yaml ^2.0.0.
> And because assets_app depends on analyzer ^3.2.0 which depends on yaml ^3.0.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with test.
> So, because assets_app depends on both flutter_test from sdk and test any, version solving failed.

How can we upgrade `integration_test` so that we can also use `test_api` 0.4.9, and `test` 1.20.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter pins it's dependencies. That's it. You have two options.

1. Wait for the next flutter release that has a version pin that you want
2. add a dependency override to get the latest version

Comment: I understand dependency pinning, and I understand that overriding pinned dependency versions may be a bad idea because I would be using a potentially non-tested mesh of dependencies. However, the question is more about why integration_test depends on an old version of test_api (0.4.3), and whether the team is aware of the issue. We can't log issues on the repo there.

Comment: See history here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commits/master/packages/flutter_test/pubspec.yaml

Someone on the Flutter team runs a tool every once-in-a-while to update all of the pinned deps. I don't think it's on any strict schedule, though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with the integration_test package

Accessing the flutter eintegration test package via cli , you can update the dependencies.

pubspec.yaml in integration_test contains this in every package you can update.
archive: 3.3.0 # THIS LINE IS AUTOGENERATED - TO UPDATE USE "flutter update-packages --force-upgrade"

So I ran "flutter update-packages --force-upgrade"
He updated the conflict and I had no more problems.